# WiFi not working, but wired connection works using same Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, atheros

**Description of the issue:**
A few weeks ago my WiFi network was working fine - until I ran this command :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then my WiFi stopped working on Ubuntu as seen below :

[image]

What I have tried so far :

1. Connecting my Ubuntu desktop using wired connection works, as seen here :[image]
2. To check if Ubuntu system sees the wireless card (AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter), I ran the command below :

   ```
   lshw -C network
   ```

Result of the above command is as follows :

```
    WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
      *-network                 
           description: Wireless interface
           product: AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
           vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
           logical name: wlan0
           version: 01
           serial: c4:6e:1f:17:cc:8a
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-66-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

3. To check if my Wireless card is ***"hard"*** blocked I ran the command below :

   ```
   rfkill list all
   ```

Result of the above command is as follows :

```
    0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Do you see any networks with `sudo iw wlan0 scan | grep -i ssid`

Comment: @nobody, the command you suggested, correctly returns my WiFi network as follows : ***"SSID: Ozark_EXT"*** , ***"SSID: MNK"*** &                                                                                         ***"SSID: Ozark"***

Comment: I'm not good with network stuff. But I think it is more a gui problem. `nmcli device status`